# bundles for symfony apart those from github

Tags: github, shared-libraries, bundle, symfony-2.1

Apart these bundles of Symfony [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony)

Does it any other bundles shared in other websites ?

Answer (score 2):

You can go to this unofficial but usefull website: http://knpbundles.com/

And since Symfony2 uses composer, if you are looking for a library you can give a look at: https://packagist.org/